# Find and select the best fitting row in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2013

The following is what I have been struggling with for a week. I have two tabs in Excel.

In the first tab, it lists the existing 401k allocation for a client in different funds, such as

```
Client Fund1 Fund2 Fund3 

John     12%   10%   15%
```

In the second tab, it lists the possible allocations for the same client with a fitting score, such as

```
Client Fund1 Fund2 Fund3 Score  

John     8%    5%     12%   30

John     10%    12%  6%     90

John     10%    8%   10%    65
```

The objective is to find the best fitting row in the second tab that satisfies two criteria:

1. The fitting score is the highest
2. None of funds has a larger  % than the existing allocation.

For the example above, although the second row has the highest fitting score 90, it is not the best fit since Fund2 has a 12%. It is larger than the existing 10%. Therefore, the third row should be selected.

Many thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't rule out multiple entries qualifying for each criterion so I suggest a helper column to identify those meeting condition 2., say something like:

```
=--AND(B2<='Tab1'!B$2,C2<='Tab1'!C$2,D2<='Tab1'!D$2)
```

say in ColumnG and then something like:

```
=MAX(IF(G:G=1,E:E))
```

entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to find the maximum score of the 2. qualifiers.

Comment: Thanks a lot pnuts! I double checked the data in the first tab. There are cases that John can have more than one allocation row. For example, John has another legacy account. Therefore, John has multiple accounts (rows) to be matched with the allocations in the 2nd tab.

Comment: And the first tab has over 200 clients.